# Linkedin error 500 Internal service error

Tags: linkedin-api

I am posting to a company site (https://api.linkedin.com/v1/companies/10901979/shares) via Linkedin API updates since a few months.

However, since a week I get the answer: 500 1518102135450 OKME4ID0PA 0 Internal service error

I've nothing changed. Any help is highly appreciated.

Best,
Nikolaus

Answer (score 0):

We were experiencing this for weeks in October during profile requests and we were finally told that we a "java bug" had been identified.  No further explanation and a few weeks later I was notified that a fix would be released soon.  After that, the issue seemed to stop, but we're now seeing a new spike in the same type of errors.

> OAuth2 Error Occurred: : =0A{=0A  "errorCode": 0,=0A  "message": "Internal API server error",=0A  "requestId": "(removed)",=0A  "status": 500,=0A  "timestamp": 1518103930225=0A}

Comment: Okay, that sounds like only Linkedin can solve this issue. Just as a comment, I've just realised that OAuth1 is used: oauth_version="1.0",oauth_nonce="(removed)",oauth_timestamp="1518101465",oauth_consumer_key="(removed)",oauth_token="(removed)",oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",oauth_signature="(removed)"

Comment: How were you able to communicate with the LinkedIn team about the api problems?